# Directional derivative of $f(x, y, z) = x^2yx + xy^2z + xyz^2$ along tangent of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I wanted to verify my solution to this problem.

> If the directional derivative of $f(x, y, z) = x^2yz + xy^2z + xyz^2$ along the tangent to the curve $x = t, y = t^2, z = 2t^4$ at $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ is $\frac{A}{\sqrt{48}}$. Then with proper justification, find the value of $A$.

Here is my attempt. The curve is,
$$\vec{r} = t\hat{i} + t^2\hat{j} + 2t^4\hat{k}$$
Its tangent would be,
$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} = 1\hat{i} + 2t\hat{j} + 8t^3\hat{k}$$
Let $\vec{u}$ be the tangent vector of $\vec{r}$ at $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$,
$$\therefore \vec{u} = 1\hat{i} + 1\hat{j} + 1\hat{k}$$
$$\text{and, } \hat{u} = \frac{1\hat{i} + 1\hat{j} + 1\hat{k}}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Gradient of $f$ is,
$$\vec{\nabla}f = 2xyz\cdot(1\hat{i} + 1\hat{j} + 1\hat{k})$$
$$\implies \vec{\nabla}f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot(1\hat{i} + 1\hat{j} + 1\hat{k})$$
So directional derivative along $\hat{u}$ is,
$$D_{\hat{u}}f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) = \vec{\nabla}f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\hat{u} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
Since we know $\frac{A}{\sqrt{48}}$ is the directional derivative along the tangent of $\vec{r}$,
$$\frac{A}{\sqrt{48}} = D_{\hat{u}}f\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \implies \frac{A}{\sqrt{48}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \implies A = 3$$
Is the solution correct?

Comment: The point you're talking about isn't included in the curve

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Would you please elaborate as to what you mean?

Comment: I guess you solved it right, just note that what you did was the directional derivative of $f$ at $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ with the direction of the tangent vector of $\vec r$ at $t=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\vec r(t=\frac{1}{2})=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8}\right)$.

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Ah yes, you are right! I should have paid greater attention to that. This problem was not from a textbook, my instructor gave it to us. I will ask them for further clarification. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, still, the method you employed to solve it is the right one.